# Primefaces global search in Datatable not working

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable

This is my xhtml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

  <h:body>
    <ui:composition template="#{templateSelection.selectedTemplate}">
      <ui:define name="docTitle">User Management</ui:define>
      <ui:define name="body">

        <h:form>

          <p:dataTable id="usrDT" var="usr" value="#{userListController.userBeans}"
                       rows="15" paginator="true"
                       rowIndexVar="row"
                       paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                       paginatorPosition="bottom"
                       filteredValue="#{userListController.filteredUserBeans}"
          >
            <f:facet name="header">
              User Management
              <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputText value="Search all fields:"/>
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('usrDT').filter()" style="width:150px"
                             placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
              </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>
            <p:column filterBy="#{row + 1}" headerText="Sl No" width="4%">
              <h:outputText value="#{row + 1}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column filterBy="#{usr.userName}" headerText="User Name" width="30%">
              <h:outputText value="#{usr.userName}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column filterBy="#{usr.userLoginId}" headerText="User ID" width="8%">
            <h:outputText value="#{usr.userLoginId}"/>
          </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
      </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

This is my bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserListController {

    @ManagedProperty("#{userServiceLayer}")
    private UserServiceLayer userServiceLayer;
    private List<UserBean> userBeans;
    private List<UserBean> filteredUserBeans;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        userBeans = userServiceLayer.getAllUserListForSearch(state, sessionScId);
    }

    public List<UserBean> getFilteredUserBeans() {
        return filteredUserBeans;
    }

    public void setFilteredUserBeans(List<UserBean> filteredUserBeans) 
    {
        this.filteredUserBeans = filteredUserBeans;
    }

    public List<UserBean> getUserBeans() {
        return userBeans;
    }

    public void setUserBeans(List<UserBean> userBeans) {
        this.userBeans = userBeans;
    }
}
```

I am creating a datatable which shows the user list and i want here to add search functionality. I have added this as describes here https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml .
Searching in Single column is working fine...But global searching is not working ....

Comment: Your datatable specifies `id="usrDT"` where the example uses the `widgetVar` attribute, not `id`.

Comment: `<p:column filterBy="#{car.brand}" headerText="Brand" footerText="exact" filterMatchMode="exact">`,you need to set the value for your `filterMatchMode`

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute called widgetVar which is help you to solve the above problem. you have to use like below
Add widgetVar in your datatable **widgetVar="usrDT"**
(it will enable filter option in your grid)

if you want to clear the filter then you can use below code
**RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('usrDT').clearFilters()");**

***NOTE:*** widgetVar value is userdefined